# Syncano async query with 'where()' filter

Tags: android, syncano

I'm using Syncano latest Android SDK (4.0.6).
Is there a way to have a async query with parameters?

```
Syncano.please(User.class).where()
```

Doesn't have a method to run it asynchronously.

But

```
Syncano.getInstance().getObjects(User.class)
```

Which has 'sendAsync()' but doesn't have 'where()' constrain.

Docs specifies:

```
Syncano.please(User.class).getAsync(callback);
```

But I don't see it in code only getAll().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an async call when using please(). Just pass SyncanoCallback object.

> ```
>    Syncano.please(Item.class).get(new SyncanoListCallback<Item>() {
>        @Override
>        public void success(ResponseGetList<Item> response, List<Item> result) {
>
>        }
>
>        @Override
>        public void failure(ResponseGetList<Item> response) {
>
>        }
>    });
> ```

You're right that async get() method is missing when using where(). It has to be fixed in the library, but you can make this call anyway saving the reference to RequestBuilder.

> ```
>    RequestBuilder<Item> please = Syncano.please(Item.class);
>    please.where().eq(Item.COLUMN_NUMBER, 11);
>    please.get(new SyncanoListCallback<Item>() {
>        @Override
>        public void success(ResponseGetList<Item> response, List<Item> result) {
>
>        }
>
>        @Override
>        public void failure(ResponseGetList<Item> response) {
>
>        }
>    });
> ```

You can also use where(), without using please(). It will look like this:

> ```
>    Where<Item> where = new Where<>();
>    where.eq(Item.COLUMN_NUMBER, 11);
>    Syncano.getInstance().getObjects(Item.class).setWhereFilter(where).sendAsync(new SyncanoListCallback<Item>() {
>        @Override
>        public void success(ResponseGetList<Item> response, List<Item> result) {
>
>        }
>
>        @Override
>        public void failure(ResponseGetList<Item> response) {
>
>        }
>    });
> ```

Comment: Oh, thanks didn't realized that setWhereFilter() is what I look for.